# numpy: multiply arbitrary shape array along first axis

Tags: python, numpy

I want to multiply an array along it's first axis by some vector.

For instance, if a is 2D, b is 1D, and a.shape[0] == b.shape[0], we can do:

```
a *= b[:, np.newaxis]
```

What if a has an arbitrary shape?  In numpy, the ellipsis "..." can be interpreted as "fill the remaining indices with ':'".  Is there an equivalent for filling the remaining axes with None/np.newaxis?

The code below generates the desired result, but I would prefer a general vectorized way to accomplish this without falling back to a for loop.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import numpy as np


def foo(a, b):
    """
    Multiply a along its first axis by b
    """
    if len(a.shape) == 1:
        a *= b
    elif len(a.shape) == 2:
        a *= b[:, np.newaxis]
    elif len(a.shape) == 3:
        a *= b[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis]
    else:
        n = a.shape[0]
        for i in range(n):
           a[i, ...] *= b[i]          

n = 10
b = np.arange(n)

a = np.ones((n, 3))
foo(a, b)
print(a)

a = np.ones((n, 3, 3))
foo(a, b)
print(a)
```

Comment: There's a lot of code here, would you be able to reduce this to a [mcve]?

Comment: OK I've tried to remove as much boilerplate as possible while still conveying my desired intent.

Comment: I don't see any loops in your code.  There's some `if/else` testing, but that's not a big deal.  Many of the `numpy` functions are just as complicated, if not more so (e.g. `np.atleast_2d`).  Getting rid of shape tests (or burying them in a function) is not `vectorization`.

Comment: @hpaulj - The else condition uses a loop (in my actual code this entire block is buried in another loop.  Indeed, the vectorization provided by the first three cases in the if/elif block are just as good from a performance perspective as the accepted solution (in my tests thus far).  The accepted solution is a lot more brief...I prefer those two lines of code to the 10 lines I had been using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just reverse the order of the axes:

```
transpose = a.T
transpose *= b
```

`a.T` is a transposed view of `a`, where "transposed" means reversing the order of the dimensions for arbitrary-dimensional `a`. We assign `a.T` to a separate variable so the `*=` doesn't try to set the `a.T` attribute; the results still apply to `a`, since the transpose is a view.

Demo:

```
In [55]: a = numpy.ones((2, 2, 3))

In [56]: a
Out[56]: 
array([[[1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]],

       [[1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]]])

In [57]: transpose = a.T

In [58]: transpose *= [2, 3]

In [59]: a
Out[59]: 
array([[[2., 2., 2.],
        [2., 2., 2.]],

       [[3., 3., 3.],
        [3., 3., 3.]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Following the idea of the accepted answer, you could skip the variable assignment to the transpose as follows:

```py
arr = np.tile(np.arange(10, dtype=float), 3).reshape(3, 10)
print(arr)
factors = np.array([0.1, 1, 10])
arr.T[:, :] *= factors
print(arr)
```

Which would print

```py
[[0. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6. 7. 8. 9.]
 [0. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6. 7. 8. 9.]
 [0. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6. 7. 8. 9.]]
[[ 0.   0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.5  0.6  0.7  0.8  0.9]
 [ 0.   1.   2.   3.   4.   5.   6.   7.   8.   9. ]
 [ 0.  10.  20.  30.  40.  50.  60.  70.  80.  90. ]]
```

Comment: Good suggestion. However, your answer only works in 2D, while the question asks for arbitrary dimensions. To make it general you need to use the ellipsis `arr.T[...] *= factors`